# Multiple Inheritance C#

Tags: c#

Suppose this is the piece of Code :

```
interface A {
    void m1();
}

interface B {
    void m1();
}

class C : A, B {
    public void m1() {

    }
}

class D{
    static void Main(string[] args){
      C c = new C();
      c.m1();
    }
}
```

Now tell me which method will C class inherit from?
A's m1() OR B's m1() ?

Comment: in this case I don't think it would matter. Anyway, classes don't inherit from intefaces, they implement them.

Comment: I know it won't but just want to clarify my doubt that which interface's method C class will implement ?

Comment: The answer is both, class `C` implements both `A` and `B` with the same implmentation. There is no inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interfaces are not classes, you are not inheriting from them but you are entering into a contract by implementing them. You ensure that all methods exist in your class. Since `m1` is implemented the contract is fulfilled.

Maybe this example is clearer:

```
interface Lion
{
    void EatZebra();
}

interface Tiger
{
    void EatZebra();
}

class CatAnimal : Lion, Tiger
{
    public void EatZebra()
    {
        Console.Write("Lions and Tigers like zebras");
    }
}
```

So both interfaces "use" this method. If you want to call one explicitely use the dot syntax:

```
void Lion.EatZebra()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Lions like zebras");
}
void Tiger.EatZebra()
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Tigers like zebras");
}
```

Feeding time:

```
CatAnimal cat = new CatAnimal();
cat.EatZebra(); // Lions and Tigers like zebras
((Lion)cat).EatZebra(); // Lions like zebras
```

[**Explicit Interface Implementation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx)

Comment: Thank mate! that 'contract' thing cleared my doubt :)

Comment: One more thing a little deeper though!
In the same code which i asked earlier, suppose Compiler is at the position of definition of m1 in C. Now tell me whom it'll notify first that 'Yes your contract is fulfilled' to B or to A ?

Comment: @AltamashShaikh: I'm not sure if i understood your question. Why should the compiler "notify" someone at all? The code will compile or it will not, that's all.

Comment: Yes i know compiler won't notify anyone, i just asked it like a more real life :D
well, let me elaborate it more technically. Suppose compiler knows that C class has a 'contract' to define m1 method from A & B interface.
Now when the compiler will check the definition of m1, obviously somewhere it'll mark the job as complete, so at this stage what would compiler think whose contract is completed A's or B's ?

Comment: @AltamashShaikh: Maybe that's a question for Eric Lippert, i simply don't know the technical background. However, i guess that the compiler looks what needs to be implemented according to the interfaces or abstract classes and checks all. If anything is missing the compiler will show you an error. Why do you think that it needs to check `A` and `B`? Since both use the same `method` signature the compiler just needs to check one implementation.  So the method that determines which members need to be implemented will run first, before the actual validation (most likely).

Answer (score 2):

This is not inheritance. Interfaces do not contain any implementation, they just describe a few known members. You can easily see this by noticing that the interface members have no bodies - they just declare the expected parameters, name, return type...

In practice this means that there is only one method in C, `m1`. However, there's two method *references*, which manifests in the fact that if you cast the C instance to interface A, you can call the A.m1 method, and if you cast it to B, you can call B.m1. Both point to the same implementation.

Now, if you want to implement two different versions of `m1`, you can. You just have to use explicit method implementation, like so:

```
void A.m1() { /* A.m1 code */ }
void B.m1() { /* B.m1 code */ }
```

This way, C itself does not have a method `m1` you could call. Howerver, casting it to interface A will allow you to call A.m1 and casting to B will allow you to call B.m1. This is useful if you have to implement two interfaces which by chance have the same method signature, but aren't actually describing the same thing.

In that case, there are two methods in C, as well as in its virtual method table.

Just remember - implementing an interface is *not* inheritance. There are a few reasons why C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance, for better and worse; and interfaces usually allow you to do almost the same thing, as long as you can use them at all :)

Comment: In that case if compiler will compile the method in C (m1) then where it'll be redirected to to find the signature of the method? in class A or in class B ?

Comment: @AltamashShaikh Neither. If the variable type is C, it will search C's virtual method table. If the type is A, it will search A's VMT, and if it is B, it will search B's VMT.

Comment: @AltamashShaikh The fact that in your case all three VMTs point to the same method is not a problem at all - in fact, that's usually the case with interfaces.

Comment: @AltamashShaikh To make this more clear, the compiler decides based on the compile-time type, not the runtime type. During runtime, it searches the VMT of the compile-time type, and only then does it actually look up the "real" address of the target method (this allows you to override virtual methods, and is facilitated through use of a special `callvirt` instruction, which handles the VMT lookup).

Answer (score 1):

There is no **multiple inheritance** in C#, in the sense that a class cannot inherit more than one **class**.

It can, however, as you point out, **implement** multiple interfaces.

An interface specifies methods that **need to be implemented** by the class implementing that interface.

In the case you are showing, the method that is called is the one implemented in **class C**, as that is the only implementation of m1. The other two are only declarations.

Answer (score 1):

The Class C isn't inheriting nothing from A and/or B. With and interface you are telling that Class C needs to implement the interface A and B. In this case, since the method name is the same, you only need to implement once.

You can even try this

```
static void Main(string[] args){
      C c = new C();
      ((A)c).m1();
      ((B)c).m1();
    }
```

It's the same method that runs.

Answer (score 0):

Method `m1` in `C` is *not* inherited. It *implements* a method declared in an interface. In this case, both `m1`'s of `A` and `B` at the same time because of matching method signatures.